# How do I capitalize a word with a hyphen. Do I capitalize the first word or both?

Tags: capitalization, hyphens

Suppose I have a word like `show-case` or `e-commerce` or `e-mail`.
How are these words supposed to be made upper-case?

1. `Show-case`, `E-commerce`, `E-mail`.

or

2. `Show-Case`, `E-Commerce`, `E-Mail`.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the word "showcase" has no hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of a sentence, first letter only, **unless if the thing's actual name has** either both words or the second word with initial caps.

> e.g. e-mail -> E-mail, but Wite-Out is Wite-Out and pro-Randy -> Pro-Randy

***Otherwise***, it's typically the generic parts (i.e. not proper nouns) of the word that are not capitalized, while **proper nouns** in the hyphenated structure are.

> e.g. pro-choice, anti-socialist, no-brainer, meat-eating;

but

> Mario-loving, anti-Luigi, pro-Republican

Comment: "Communist" is a proper noun, no? It certainly is if "Republican" is, at any rate.

Comment: "Communist" is proper when referring to a Communist Party or related things. When talking about the ideology *in general*, it often isn't, and thus is "communist". Though context may contradict that.

Comment: Do the same rules apply to headings and table headers?

Comment: @JordanJ - Assuming the heading is written in Title Case, that makes for an interesting twist on your question. (Perhaps you should have made that part of your original question, especially if that's the situation you are most interested in.) I've seen headlines in both formats: (e.g. _Pro-life Groups Rally in Capitol_ vs. _Pro-Life Groups Rally in Capitol_), so I believe it's more a style issue than a right-way/wrong-way issue.